# OUTPUT 2 LOWEST VALUES IN ARRAY OF EXCEL DATA

Tags: excel

I have file of ~40K lines that shows Company, Part Number, and Price.  Sample below.

```
Company PART NUMBER PRICE
COMPANY14   4063-16082-3     $4,350.00 
COMPANY51   4063-16082-3     $3,481.00 
COMPANY11   321-400-703-0    $3,275.00 
COMPANY11   4063-16082-3     $3,200.00 
COMPANY11   283200-1005  $3,200.00 
COMPANY42   321-400-703-0    $2,800.00 
COMPANY4    4063-16082-3     $2,750.00 
COMPANY4    283200-1005  $2,750.00 
COMPANY35   283200-1005  $2,495.00 
COMPANY59   283200-1005  $2,250.00 
COMPANY24   4063-16082-3     $1,800.00 
COMPANY64   321-400-703-0    $1,145.00 
COMPANY8    4063-16082-3     $1,000.00 
COMPANY60   321-400-703-0    $1,000.00 
COMPANY60   283200-1005  $1,000.00 
COMPANY63   283200-1005  $325.00
```

I need to get the 2 lowest Price values for each Part Number and the corresponding Company. Here is what I need or something similar.

```
PART NUMBER Company PRICE
283200-1005 COMPANY63   325
283200-1005 COMPANY60   1000
321-400-703-0   COMPANY60   1000
321-400-703-0   COMPANY64   1145
4063-16082-3    COMPANY8    1000
4063-16082-3    COMPANY24   1800
```

I did a Pivot and have used MIN function in pivot, but not sure how to get the TWO lowest values in format above.  Here is the pic of pivot I used.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formula solution

Assuming Sheet2 is the source data,  and the target data has the part number in column A, the Comapny in B and the price in C.

```
C2:
=AGGREGATE(15, 6, Sheet2!$C$2:$C$17/(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$17=Sheet4!A2), 1)

C3:
=AGGREGATE(15, 6, Sheet2!$C$2:$C$17/(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$17=Sheet4!A2), 2)

B2: (array formula: Ctrl+Shift+Enter)
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$17,MATCH(1,(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$17=Sheet4!A2)*((Sheet2!$C$2:$C$17=C2))))
```

You can copy `B2` and paste down. For column C, copy both `C2 and C3` then paste down in column C.

Comment: AGGREGATE does not need CSE, It is by default an array type formula like SUMPRODUCT

Comment: @ScottCraner it is less flexible than `SumProduct` though, i.e. it *sucks* with row arrays.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: @ScottCraner too long for this format but the aggregate function is admittedly designed for columns of data as stated in here https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df

Comment: Again I do not understand as I prefer this over MATCH just because it can look through a 2 dimensional array. `=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A1:D4)/(A1:D4 = "Blah"),1)` will return the first row in which `Blah` was found in the range, and you can change to `COLUMN(A1:D4)` to return the column.

Comment: Well I didn't say it doesn't work at all with rows/arrays. But for the least some criteria for the 2nd parameter dont work in that case (i.e. option 1, ignore hidden). This is stated on that reference page, as for my own experience I have had some trouble where some (complex) idea works for columns but less well with rows. Then I found that statement on the ref page *"The AGGREGATE function is designed for columns of data, or vertical ranges"*. "Designed for" doesn't mean "works only for", of course.

Comment: Ahhhh! yes, but so does SUBTOTAL.  EXCEL has no good way to ignore hidden columns, only hidden rows.

Comment: @A.S.H - I've always thought of AGGREGATE as 'the little engine that almost could'. It seems like it was put out in a rush and only half finished. It would have been easy to add cyclic calculation to **all** of the sub-functions instead of only those 14 and above. Similarly, it would have been easy to trim full column references down to the worksheet's used range like SUM, SUMIFS, etc. They just didn't finish it before they shoved it out in a new release.

Comment: @A.S.H Thanks a lot for the feedback, helps a ton.

Comment: @yampacountry Welcome, glad to help. Please think of [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) when it solves correctly your issue, by checking the gray checkmark (on the top-left) turning it green. Thanks.